# How can put two progress bars in the same tick event in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, cpu-usage

I am having a bit of trouble putting two progress bars in the same tick event. The second progress bar either loads to 0% or 100% and nothing between these two values. This is the code i have so far.

```
        void timeElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = (int)(power.BatteryLifePercent * 100);
        label1.Text = string.Format("{0}%", (power.BatteryLifePercent * 100));

        cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
        cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
        cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

        var unused = cpuCounter.NextValue();

        progressBar2.Value = (int)(cpuCounter.NextValue());
        label2.Text = "CPU  " + progressBar2.Value.ToString() + "%";
    }
```

The first progress bar loads fine and the battery percentage is correct however the second progress bar always is on 100% or 0%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't read the counter 2 times in a row without waiting at least 1 second in between. If you remove your first call to `cpuCounter.NextValue()` in the method, everything should start working fine, otherwise the second call always returns 0 or 100, as I my testing has shown. As far as I can see, you don't use that value anywhere.

Change your method like this and it should work:

```
void timeElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = (int)(power.BatteryLifePercent * 100);
    label1.Text = string.Format("{0}%", (power.BatteryLifePercent * 100));

    cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
    cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
    cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

    //var unused = cpuCounter.NextValue();

    progressBar2.Value = (int)(cpuCounter.NextValue());
    label2.Text = "CPU  " + progressBar2.Value.ToString() + "%";
}
```

I got my infor from [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.nextvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If the calculated value of a counter depends on two counter reads, the
>   first read operation returns 0.0. Resetting the performance counter
>   properties to specify a different counter is equivalent to creating a
>   new performance counter, and the first read operation using the new
>   properties returns 0.0. The recommended delay time between calls to
>   the NextValue method is one second, to allow the counter to perform
>   the next incremental read.

As mentioned there, the very first call will still return 0.

Comment: Thanks. The problem has gone. By the way do you know how to change the color of the progress bar?